# Java арифметические задачи

Tags: java

Как в Java возвести синус в 3 степень?

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class Exam {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 17;
    int y = 11;
    int e = 19;
    int a = 21;
    int n = 3;
    int z
z = ( ( log (x + y) - sin(x)^3    * (pow (y,2)))        /  (3 * (sqrt (a * y))  ) + (pow (e,y));
System.out.println("z=" + z);
} }
```

Comment: sin(x)*sin(x)*sin(x) не вариант?

Comment: или такой Math.pow(sin(x), 3)

Answer (score 0):

```
double x = 1; double y=Math.pow(Math.sin(x),3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуйте

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 17;
    int y = 11;
    int e = 19;
    int a = 21;
    int n = 3;
    int z =
        (int)
            ((Math.log(x + y) - Math.pow(Math.sin(x), 3) * (Math.pow(y, 2)))
                    / (3 * (Math.sqrt(a * y)))
                + Math.pow(e, y));
    System.out.println("z=" + z);
  }
```